# Hibernate Jboss logging and Log4j CVE Vulnerability

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jboss

I'm working on a Spring boot project, and i'm checking if it's concerned by this vulnerabilty,
I don't have any Log4j core dependency,
But i'm using hibernate core 5.0.12 that use jboss logging 3.3.1
And when i checked the jboss logging dependency, i see the log4j:
<version.org.apache.log4j>1.2.16</version.org.apache.log4j>
<version.org.apache.logging.log4j>2.0</version.org.apache.logging.log4j>
And i'm not using the jboss loggin for my logs, i'm using Slf4j,
So, shall i exlude this jboss logging dependency from my project ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to exclude jboss logging (would hibernate even work without it?).
If you don't have `log4j-core` as a dependency, you're not affected.
See also https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have checked tha apache officil site and that's what i have found concerning the log4j 1:  "A security vulnerability, CVE-2019-17571 has been identified against Log4j 1. Log4j includes a SocketServer that accepts serialized log events and deserializes them without verifying whether the objects are allowed or not. This can provide an attack vector that can be expoited. Since Log4j 1 is no longer maintained this issue will not be fixed. Users are urged to upgrade to Log4j 2."

Comment: I'm still confused beacause i'm not using the log4j core, and our security team are saying that if we have the jboss-logmanager dependency, we are concerned by this vulnerability because jboss dependency is using the version 1 of log4j that is obsolete

Comment: Log4j 1.x is not affected by CVE-2021-44228, however it is affected by CVE-2021-4104, so you should look into the logging properties or remove `JMSAppender` class from your log4j 1.x dependency, explained here: https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2021-4104

Comment: jboss-logging is just a logging facade. It definitely does not expose either CVE. The `jboss-logmanager` is a log manager and does not have this CVE either. It does not use log4j 1 or 2 at all.

Comment: Yes, but when i'm checking the Jboss pom.xml i see that there is some dependency on the log4j 1, and like i said our security team are saying that we need to do an upgrade to log4j 2.17, and i don't see how i can even  do it in this case because i'm not using it directly, it's used by hibernate